# Mapreduce to tokenize 3 columns

Tags: java, hadoop, while-loop, mapreduce, stringtokenizer

I'm writing a map function that needs to read 3 columns. I have a text file as:

```
1234567 12234254 40
```

How would I change a simple wordcount mapper's stringtokenizer to be able to read the 3 rows while using the while loop

```
public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken()); 
    context.write(word, one); 
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That code works exactly like you're wanting, but as stated in Javadoc

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code

Instead, use a for loop

```
private Text t = new Text();
... 

for (String column : value.toString().split("\\s+")) {
    t.set(column);
    context.write(t, ONE);
}
```